# Delete list box item and update database in C#

Tags: c#, listbox, windows-forms-designer

This is probably classic noob question but Im really new to C# (Windows Forms App), and I  would appreciate any help on this. So, Im looking for the way to do this:
I have one list box with items that represent database table entries. I want to delete a row in database table by deleting list box item. Is there any way to assign value to list box item (primary key for example) so I could use it to update db table when deleting list box item?

Thanks for your time!

EDIT: Its Db4o database.

Comment: yes there is a lot of ways, what have you try?

Comment: @ArsenMkrt - Well nothing that actually gave any results. I cant find the way to bind Db4o database to `DataSource`. I tried with setting `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` property to listbox item but that doesnt seem to work...

Comment: try to Google first, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25669/An-introduction-to-LINQ-for-db4o. here is how you can get data from Db4o db, and there are a lot of examples how to set datasource to listbox... stackoverflow is purposed for real questions

Comment: OK, sorry for asking unreal question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it manually:

```
public class MyDBRecord
{
    public int ID { get; set; } 
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public MyDBRecord(int _id, string _text)
    {
        ID = _id;
        Text = _text;
    }
}
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.DisplayMember = "Text";
    listBox1.ValueMember = "ID";

    listBox1.Items.Add(new MyDBRecord(1, "abc"));
    listBox1.Items.Add(new MyDBRecord(2, "def"));
    listBox1.Items.Add(new MyDBRecord(3, "hij"));
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyDBRecord Selected;

    Selected = listBox1.SelectedItem as MyDBRecord;

    if (Selected != null)
        MessageBox.Show(Selected.ID.ToString());     
}
```

Comment: OK thank you, Im gonna try this.